# How can I use mysqldump with --hex-blob in gulpfile?

Tags: mysql, npm, gulp, binary

I have a gulpfile.js. I want to dump the mysql database but have problems with the type "varbinary", so I want to use the arg --hex-blob because this was a solution for someone else with the same problem here.

The problem is that the export with mysqldump looks different then the export with phpmyadmin. "varbinary" is always wrapped with the "NOFORMAT_WRAP"-function which doesn't exist in MySQL-Server.

mysqldump is the newest version from npm.

Thanks.

dump.sql created with mysqldump:

```
INSERT INTO
  `session` (`session_id`) VALUES
  (NOFORMAT_WRAP(
      "##X'316236316d396d683275716834636d6b697035756e6b39766d67'##"
    )
```

Same with phpmyadmin (which is expected):

```
INSERT INTO `session` (`session_id`) VALUES
(0x316236316d396d683275716834636d6b697035756e6b39766d67)
```

gulpfile.js:

```
const mysqlDump     = require('mysqldump');

// database dump
gulp.task('dumpDatabase', () => {
    return mysqlDump({
        connection: {
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'who',
            password: 'pass',
            database: 'test'
        },
        dumpToFile: '../../../database/backup-' + today + '.sql'
    });
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('dumpDatabase'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysqldump you can have the entire list of options.

In your case, you need to add the dump option like this.

```
// database dump
gulp.task('dumpDatabase', () => {
    return mysqlDump({
        connection: {
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'who',
            password: 'pass',
            database: 'test'
        },
        dump: {
            data: {
                format : false
            }
        },
        dumpToFile: '../../../database/backup-' + today + '.sql'
    });
});
```